# Bresser MikroCam SP 5.0 Does not have Driver for Anchor Chips (ID 0547:1236)

Tags: linux, camera, driver, webcam, uvc

I have been assigned to use the **Bresser MikroCam SP 5.0 camera**. This camera is using **Anchor Chips Inc** with a **vendor ID of 0547**. I have tried to find a driver for allowing the chip to be recognized as a video input but it shows me a dead end. For now, the only way to communicate and streaming is through the provided software in windows. I am trying to use the camera with the ROS but first I need it to be recognized as a camera. Do you have any idea how can I resolve it? I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** and my kernel is **5.4.0-65-generic**. I also have tried using **cheese**, **gucview**, **camorama**, **AstroDMx** **Capture**, and **v4l2**.

Here is the output from `lsusb` :

`Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0547:1236 Anchor Chips, Inc.`

Here is the output from `dmesg` :

```
[15285.634177] usb 1-9: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[15285.790034] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=0547, idProduct=1236, bcdDevice= 0.02
[15285.790040] usb 1-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[15285.790043] usb 1-9: Product: USB2.0 Camera
[15285.790045] usb 1-9: Manufacturer: TP
```

Here is the output from `usb-devices` :

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=08 Cnt=03 Dev#=  9 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0547 ProdID=1236 Rev=00.02
S:  Manufacturer=TP
S:  Product=USB2.0 Camera
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

I have posted this on askubuntu and still does not have a reply.

Comment: This is the wrong place to post this, as you probably already know.

Comment: I know about this, I just want to try my luck @JamesZ